# Are functions local to a cpp body thread safe? If so what about calling static functions from it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, local, static-methods

I have a lot of multithreading bugs since I introduced a second worker thread. The issues are minor and hard to trace. My latest indications point to

```
class MyOtherClass {
    static String defaultName;
    static String getDefaultName() {return defaultName;}
}
```

which is being used by:

```
result plainLocalFunction() {
    result r = E_SUCCESS;
    String fallbackName = MyOtherClass::getDefaultName();
    //Do other stuff with locals.
    return r;
}
```

I've been ages debugging this and I can only suppose that either the `plainLocalFunction` is shares its locals between threads or that that the call to `getDefaultName()` involves writing to a static variable which is not thread safe? Thanks for your time.

Comment: class String is `Osp::Base::String` not `std::string`

Comment: I don't see anything problematic in above code, though your wording _"writing to a static"_ confuses me. The code you posted only ever makes a local copy of a static variable, which (hopefully!?) is not modified by the copy constructor, which (very hopefully?!) shouldn't need to modify any variables that don't have automatic storage. Writing to a static global is of course a different matter, but I see no such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static variables inside a function would render your function not re-entrant and not thread safe.

If you have just local variables in a function then each thread stack will have its own copy of those variables and the function will be thread safe.

Comment: @John: If the static member is being modified across different threads then it is not thread safe. Assume an object of class in one thread trying to read the static member and in another an object of the same class trying to write to the static member.Then there is a race condition.

Comment: Thank you Als. What do you think about my call to a static method? Would it's returned value be unsafe despite `defaultName` being written only at start up time?

Comment: @John: If `defaultName` gets written only at startup and in a threadsafe manner then consecutive reads of it will be threadsafe(since reading a variable from multiple threads doesnt trigger a race condition).

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are absolutely not thread safe if you write to them (here: defaultName).
Reading (if Nobody writes to it) should be okay though and I don't think calling a static function (or a dynamic one for what matters) is thread-unsafe if there are no thread-unsafe things going on in it.

Use [CriticalSections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) (for example) to protect your variables that are used by several threads (and at least one thread might write to it).

Comment: Well, to be honest, for cases like the above code, this is a non-concern most of the time, because static constructors run before `main` is called. In other words, before any concurrency takes place. If the default name is not changed _later_ in the program (and there is neither a sane reason to do that given it's a "default", nor does the code show such a thing), there is not truly a need for critical sections.

Comment: Yes, that was why I wrote "..not thread safe if you write to them ..", maybe I should have put more emphasis on the "You".